# Show that $n$ even $ \land\ f^{n}(b)<0 \implies f$ has strict maxima in $b$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have already asked this question once, but did not quit understand all the steps in the provided hint. So here goes:

- The $n$-th derivative of $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhood around a point $b$
- $f'(b)=f''(b)=...=f^{(n-1)}(b)=0$
- $f^{(n)}(b)\neq 0 $

From the conditions above I am supposed to come to the following conclusions:

- $n$ even $\land\: f^{n}(b)<0 \implies f$ has strict maxima in $b$
- $n$ even $\land\: f^{n}(b)>0 \implies f$ has strict minima in $b$
- $n$ odd $\implies f$ has no extreme in $b$

My attempt is based on Taylor's formula:

$f(x) = f(b) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {f^{(k)}(b)}{k!} (x-b)^{k} + R_{n}(x) \iff f(x)-f(b)= R_{n}(x)$

$R_{n}(x)$ is the Lagrange remainder $\iff R_{n}(x) = \frac {f^{(n)}(b+c \ (x-b)))}{n!} \ (x-b)^{n}$ , $0<c<1$

So $f(x)-f(b) = \frac {f^{(n)}(b+c \ (x-b)))}{n!} \ (x-b)^{n}$

This is where I get stuck.

In order to move forward, I am supposed to understand that $ \frac {f^{(n)}(b+c \ (x-b)))}{n!} \ (x-b)^{n} = \frac {(x-b)^n}{n!} (f^{(n)} (b) + \epsilon(x)), \epsilon(x)$ approaches $0$ when $x$ approaches $b$.

The only way for me to understand the equality above is by assuming that all continuous functions can be linearized in a (small enough) neighbourhood of b, but I don't know how to prove that or even if it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Yes, as you said, by Taylor-Young formula, we can write for $ x $ close to $ b $,

$$f(x)-f(b)=$$
$$\frac{(x-b)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(b)\Bigl(1+\epsilon(x)\Bigr)$$

If $n $ is even , then $(x-b)^n\ge 0$.

$1+\epsilon(x)>0$ because $ \epsilon(x) \to 0$ which means that for $ x $ near $ b $, we have
$$-\frac 12 <\epsilon(x)<\frac 12$$
and
$$0<\frac 12 <1+\epsilon(x)$$

You can conclude.
What can you say about the sign of $ f(x)-f(b)$.